# How to set SQL-Always-On in Kubernetes Linux container?

Tags: sql-server, docker, kubernetes, failovercluster

I raised 3 pods of SQL servers in Kubernetes:

- 1 as a primary DB
- 2 others as Secondary DBs

I want to set SQL-Always-On feature between those 3 DBs in a way that:

- In SSMS the 3 DBs will be "Synchronized"
- In SSMS I want to be able to click "Failover" on Primary DB (then Secondary DB become active)

What are the steps for creating this mechanism?